# How to use observable property of an observable array to change display property in UI?

Tags: knockout.js

```js
this.inviteeEmailList = ko.observableArray([]);

this.status = ko.observable();

var emails = ["hello","test","obseervableArray"];

for(var j in emails)
                {
                    var emailList = {};
                    emailList.email = emails[j];
                    emailList.status = ko.observable(this.status());
                    this.inviteeEmailList.push(emailList);
                }

/**
* after getting response , changing the value of observable to true.
*/
var done = function()
{
  var self = this;
  self.status(true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="foundEmail" class="suEmailIdContainer" data-bind="foreach : inviteeEmailList">

            <span data-bind="text:$data.email"></span>
            <div data-bind="text:$data.status"></div>

            <span data-bind="if: $data.status">
                <span>success</span><br/>
            </span>

            <span data-bind="if: !$data.status">
                <span>fail</span><br/>
            </span>
</div>
```

I have an observableArray with an observable property.
As given here:

```
for(var j in emails)
{
    var emailList = {};
    emailList.email = emails[j];
    emailList.status = ko.observable(this.status());
    this.inviteeEmailList.push(emailList);
}
```

I am sending request to server and after getting response, I am changing the value of the observable (i.e. `this.status()`) to `true` or `false` accordingly.
In html I am trying to access `$data.status` inside `foreach` of `inviteeEmailList`.

But that value is not reflected in the observable property `emailList.status`.

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24710/ and let us know for further clarifications  . cheers .

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this. Now I want to set status for different emails in the observableArray, for which I am getting the response from server. How I can change the corresponding status of the email? I tried using a counter. which I tried incrementing after getting response, but that is also not working. @super cool

Comment: I have used the counter by giving the counter as index of the observableArray, so that I can get the corresponding status.

invitedEmails = 0;

this.inviteeEmailList()[invitedEmails].status(true);

Comment: are you getting response at a time ? if so u can simply place the `foreach` under your ajax success and do the same .

Comment: What if you add additional <span data-bind="text:$root.status"></span>. Each email have their own status (not for each email), and when done, you set root status. If you need that status would be one for all, use computed observables.

Comment: No for each emails, I am sending different requests.
So response wont come at a time. @super cool

Comment: I want to show status if status is false, else if status is true , I want to show some icon. @VikciaR

Comment: well if you are requesting for status for every email and later pushing that's not gonna work well with `ko` . performance at stake . i advise you to get the list of email with status and keep it in observableArray later query it client side inside existing foreach. you can avoid `n` number of requests (presuming you have smaller data).

Comment: [something like this eddited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24710/) I tried

Comment: And how you change that status?

Comment: There is no other way to do this? I am trying to get index of the email from that observable array some how. If any how I can get that, may be my problem will be solved. I tried using indexOf, but this also wont work, since  array is with object form. @super cool

Comment: @VikciaR I tried hard coding the counter to 0, and it changed the status for that particular object of that array i.e. for the first email. But this variable is also not working, since it is incremented already before it can change the status.

Comment: `I am trying to get index of the email from that observable array ` can you please elaborate on this line possible add some code which will help us understand and please feel free to edit my fiddle post with additional code .

Comment: try this `ko.utils.arrayForEach(emails,function(item){ emailList.email = item  }) ;`  replace it .

Comment: I solved this problem. After getting response I have searched for the email in the observable array in a for loop, since I know for which email I am getting response. Now I got the index of the object, where I need to change the status.thanks. :) @super cool

Comment: gald your issue is done . so you want me to post as answer or else you can do the same . cheers

Comment: You can post the solution as answer. So that it might be help full for some one else in future.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var emails = [{
    'email': 's@s.com',
    'status': false
}, {
    'email': 'e@e.com',
    'status': true
}]

var ViewModel = function () {
    console.log(emails)
    var self = this;

    function inner(email, status) {
        var emailList = this;
        emailList.email = ko.observable(email);
        emailList.status = ko.observable(status);
    }
    self.inviteeEmailList = ko.observableArray();
    self.failStatus = ko.observable('i am failed');
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(emails,function(item){
        self.inviteeEmailList.push(new inner(item.email, item.status));
    });
    console.log(self.inviteeEmailList())
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.liveExample {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #EEEEDD;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    max-width: 655px;
}
.liveExample input {
    font-family: Arial;
}
.liveExample b {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.liveExample p {
    margin-top: 0.9em;
    margin-bottom: 0.9em;
}
.liveExample select[multiple] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
}
.liveExample h2 {
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div  data-bind="foreach:inviteeEmailList">
                <span data-bind="text:$data.email"></span>
                <span data-bind="text:$data.status"></span> 

                <span data-bind="if: $data.status">
                    <b>Hiee i am True</b>
                </span>

                <span data-bind="if: !$data.status">
                    <span data-bind="text: $root.failStatus "></span><br/>
                </span>
    <br/>
 </div>
```

Above code can be used to solve the question.

Comment: Awesome job going back and answering your own question so future users can benefit from it as well! Truly commendable!

Comment: Thanx @Chris Britt